# ASP.NET 5 / MVC 6 AppSettings

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

[TL;DR]: How do I access AppSettings data without using dependency injection in MVC 6?

I'm trying to reach some app setting data from a _Layout.cshtml in my MVC 6 app.

I understand (and have implemented) the "Options" patterns as described at http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html#using-options-and-configuration-objects.

It works well when I need to inject some settings into specific controllers, but I can't quite work out how to inject Options into a shared _Layout.cshtml, since it doesn't have an associated controller.

Is there a way to access Configuration data without using DI?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I worked it out.  In the view, the following will work, as long as the Options service is configured as per the above link.

```
@inject Microsoft.Extensions.OptionsModel.IOptions<MySettingsClass> Options
```

Answer (score 1):

I have recently wrote blog on this.

Please have a look here:

https://neelbhatt40.wordpress.com/2015/12/15/getting-a-configuration-value-in-asp-net-5-vnext-and-mvc-6/